# Keras - Sentiment Analysis on IMDB

Tags: keras

I am new to Keras & ML concepts. I am trying to perform sentiment analysis using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fchollet/keras/master/examples/imdb_cnn_lstm.py. I have saved the model using model.save("imdb_cnn_lstm.h5") and loaded the model to perform prediction on a new text like

```
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import re

model = load_model('imdb_cnn_lstm.h5')
word_to_id = imdb.get_word_index()

testString = raw_input('Enter your test to be analyzed:')

strip_special_chars = re.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+")
testString = testString.lower().replace("<br />", " ")
testString=re.sub(strip_special_chars, "", testString.lower())
print("Cleaned Data ", testString)

words = testString.split() #split string into a list
x_test = [[word_to_id[word] if (word in word_to_id and word_to_id[word]<=20000) else 0 for word in words]]
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=100) # Should be same which you used for training data
vector = np.array([x_test.flatten()])
print("Prediction is ",model.predict(vector),model.predict_classes(vector))
```

For a text like "it's a disappointing movie" the output is 0.5724526 ( output of model.predict(vector)) 
For a text like "it's an awesome movie" the output is 0.57088572 (output of model.predict(vector))
What should I tune to get a better prediction/ classification? I assume for the model predicts 1 for positive sentiment and 0 for negative sentiment.

Comment: You could try using an LSTM, with pretrained word embeddings. I think there is an example of this that performs well

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py?

Comment: Yes, I really havent experimented deeply with convolution layers though, but you could try implementing a word2vec module and train this network with pretrained word embeddings since their used for convolution layers too. Without pretrained embedding, keras embdding layer is training itself, so essentially, you need to train one less layer, giving yourself an advantage

Comment: [check this out](https://github.com/alexander-rakhlin/CNN-for-Sentence-Classification-in-Keras)...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check this